# eBay API CORS request using JavaScript returns undefined

Tags: javascript, cors, ebay-api

I want to fetch JSON data from [eBay Sandbox](http://svcs.sandbox.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=NiraliAc-FlashSal-SBX-7d56b4536-d82a9262&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-US&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON&callback=_cb_findItemsByKeywords&REST-PAYLOAD&keywords=harry%20potter&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=3&itemFilter(0).name=MaxPrice&itemFilter(0).value=25&itemFilter(0).paramName=Currency&itemFilter(0).paramValue=USD&itemFilter(1).name=FreeShippingOnly&itemFilter(1).value=true&itemFilter(2).name=ListingType&itemFilter(2).value(0)=AuctionWithBIN&itemFilter(2).value(1)=FixedPrice&itemFilter(2).value(2)=StoreInventory) using JavaScript

I tried getting it through CORS request (as it is a cross domain request) but it returns undefined. I tried lots of different code but I haven't found any solutions.
What I want to do is that fetch the products from eBay and display them in my Chrome extension.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution by making a CORS request and using the CORS Anywhere API from https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/

```
var cors_api_url = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';
function doCORSRequest(options, printResult) {
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open(options.method, cors_api_url + options.url);
    x.onload = x.onerror = function() {
        printResult(
            options.method + ' ' + options.url + '\n' +
            x.status + ' ' + x.statusText + '\n\n' +
            (x.responseText || '')
        );
    };
    x.send(options.data);
}
(function() {
    var outputField = document.getElementById('output');
    new1();
    function new1() {
        // e.preventDefault();
        doCORSRequest({
            method: 'GET',
            url: url,
        }, function printResult(result) {
            //result contains the response
            //write your code here
        });
    };
})();
```

Source: https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/blob/master/demo.html

(Live example: https://robwu.nl/cors-anywhere.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can send a GET request to the URL.

```
const http = require('http');

let url = 'http://svcs.sandbox.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=NiraliAc-FlashSal-SBX-7d56b4536-d82a9262&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-US&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON&callback=_cb_findItemsByKeywords&REST-PAYLOAD&keywords=harry%20potter&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=3&itemFilter(0).name=MaxPrice&itemFilter(0).value=25&itemFilter(0).paramName=Currency&itemFilter(0).paramValue=USD&itemFilter(1).name=FreeShippingOnly&itemFilter(1).value=true&itemFilter(2).name=ListingType&itemFilter(2).value(0)=AuctionWithBIN&itemFilter(2).value(1)=FixedPrice&itemFilter(2).value(2)=StoreInventory';

http.get(url, res => {
    let body = '';
    res.on('data', data => body += data);
    res.on('end', () => {
        console.log(body);
    });
});
```

Comment: I am working with javascript in browser. It gives ```Reference error: require is not defined```

Comment: You can use jQuery $.get() method, or `XMLHttpRequest` as in [this](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) page.

Comment: It will give an error as it a cross domain request. I already tried that.

Comment: Hey thanks for help. I found a solution. I have added it as an answer.